# Prove the functor $[n]\to [n]\star [n]$ preserves inner anodyne

Tags: simplicial-stuff

Let $f:\Delta\to \Delta$ be the functor given by $[n]\mapsto [n]\star[n]=[2n+1]$. We can extend $f$ cocontinuously to a functor 
$$f_!: SSet\to SSet$$
 (that is, the left adjoint of the functor $f^*$. Notice that $f_!S \neq S\star S$ in general.)

**My question**: Does $f_!$ send (inner) anodyne maps to (inner) anodyne maps? When I draw a picture, then it seems quite sure that the answer should be true.